# How do I add something to my PATH on the server side when using VSCode Remote SSH?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using Visual Studio Code's Remote SSH extension to develop code on my university's linux cluster, which still has an older version of git installed (1.8.3.1). This causes errors with the "GitLens" extension that I'm also using.

I tried solving this problem by just cloning my own version of git into "~/git" and compiling it there for myself. Then I added

`export PATH=$HOME/git:$PATH`

to my .zshrc file.

The problem is that vscode doesn't seem to care what I put in the .zshrc file. Is there another way to set a custom git executable on the server side?

I also tried doing the same in the ".bashrc" file, just in case vscode uses bash for some reason. This also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands at the remote end of an SSH tunnel are executed using non-interactive shell so I think `~/.zshrc` is not executed. Use `~/.zshenv` or `~/.zprofile`. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html.

Comment: Changing the PATH in `~/zshenv` worked for me, thank you!

Comment: In case this doesn't seem to work: VSCode doesn't stop the server when you disconnect. I had to kill it manually. Then a fresh connection sure found the new env vars.